# How to provide user permission to read, write on `/dev/sdax`? What is the syntax?

Tags: partitioning, permissions, users, chmod, chown

I have two my hard disk divided into two partition (apart from swap).
First one is `/dev/sda3` on which I have my ubuntu installation. Second one is `/dev/sda1`. Now, when I try to copy a file to `/dev/sda1`, I need to do a sudo, because my user does not have permission.

How do I give read, write permission to my user? I know `chmod 777` is a bad idea. How about `chown` or `chgrp`?

by the way, `/dev/sda1` is mounted as `/media/hood`, so what should be the syntax my command?

I have two my hard disk divided into two partition (apart from swap).
First one is `/dev/sda3` on which I have my ubuntu installation. Second one is `/dev/sda1`. Now, when I try to copy a file to `/dev/sda1`, I need to do a sudo, because my user does not have permission.

How do I give read, write permission to my user? I know `chmod 777` is a bad idea. How about `chown` or `chgrp`?

The output of `mount` command is as as follows:

```
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devp
ts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/chirag/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=chirag)
```

/dev/sda1 on /media/hood type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)

Comment: You should not be copying to the raw partition/device `/dev/sd*`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the ownership allowed me to copy without doing `sudo`.
command used:

```
sudo chown chirag:chirag /media/hood/ -R
```

Where, chirag:chirag is user:group.